# Remove element from WKWebView loaded via URL swift

Tags: javascript, html, swift

I'm using WKWebView and i got a webview loaded via URL, and it's working perfectly

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.monstie.fr/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I'm using a js file to inject some CSS but I would like to remove some element like the "href" of  (for example)  with javascript and without load all the html in a variable.

My question is : how can i use this javascript code with swift ?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mylinkclass").removeAttribute("href");
```

thanks ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WKWebView` has a method that allows you to evaluate arbitrary javascript

`func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String,
      completionHandler completionHandler: ((AnyObject!,
                                 NSError!) -> Void)?)`

You can call remove your hrefs be calling 
`webView.evaluateJavascript('document.getElementsByClassName("mylinkclass").removeAttribute("href");')`

[Docs from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:)

Comment: I tried your method and a tuto  http://www.n0doz.com/index.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=17, and i put my js code in the variable and i still get a error (from the variable error) like : Error: Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo=0x7fb3984c8b20 {NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}

Comment: And I tried with a getElementByID it's working perfectly but when i use getElementsByClassName it's doesn't work